# Error 500 al enviar excel con muchos registros por email con Mailable Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mail

El problema surge cuando envio muchos registros en excel por mailable de Laravel, porque cuando envio pocos registros desde la misma función si se envia correctamente.

Mi función:

```
            foreach ($users as  $user)
            {
                set_time_limit(300);
                $date = new Carbon(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($user->frecuency)));
                // $when = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);
                $samples = $this->getSamples($user->getTemplate, $user->last_send, $user->type_frecuency, $user->frecuency);
                Mail::to($user->email)
                ->later($date, new reporterEmail($samples, $user->getTemplate, $user));
           }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los logs aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ recién subo la foto de el log, parece ser problema de memoria, como haría ahi?

Comment: Mmm... no llego a leer esa letra tan pequeña. Intenta copiar y pegar como texto el mensaje de error. Si te dice que se acaba la memoria, revisa en el php.ini la clave `memory_limit` cuánto tiene seteado.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes)

Comment: Ok, lo agregué a la pregunta. Veo que alguien ya te respondió, revisa si eso te sirve. Si estás en un ambiente de desarrollo, eso te puede servir, pero tal vez en un hosting no tengas esa posibilidad. Personalmente siempre intento configurar mis ambientes de desarrollo con las mismas características que el de producción para no llevarme sorpresas

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Si, me ayudó en el entorno local, pero en el de desarrollo lo extraño es que no llegan los correos y no arroja ningun error 500, hacer el proceso ok y no muestra ningun error, pero el email nunca llega, pudieras ayudarme en un chat privado porfa?

Comment: creo que abriendo otra pregunta sería mejor, porque sólo entro a so en momentos que tengo libre. Además a una pregunta la pueden ver otros usuarios que pueden aportar más opciones e ideas de lo que puede estar pasando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu php.ini tienes que aumentar el memory limit, siempre este parámetro viene con valores bajos, tambien recomiendo aumentar el max_execution_time
En caso que uses Nginx

```
/etc/php*/fpm/php.ini
memory_limit = 2048M
```

En caso de apache

```
/etc/php/*.*/cli/php.ini
 memory_limit = 2048M
```

En caso de Xammp

```
/xampp/php/php.ini 
memory_limit = 2048M
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado, se demora pero funciona, gracias. ahora mi problema surge en el entorno de desarrollo pero eso es otra cosa, tu solucion fue para el local, Gracias.